# Namespaces in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces, traits, spl-autoload-register

Please look at this and tell me what do you think about this:

### 1)**I have the this structure:**

```
   | - index.php
        | - test
              | classes 
                  |- someclass.php
              | traits
                  |- sometrait.php
```

### **2) And code:**

> **It's Index.php and It's works:**

```
*<?php
        use \Test\Classes as Classes;
        use \Test\Traits as Traits;

        spl_autoload_register(...);

        echo Classes\Someclass::start();

    ?>*
```

**It's Someclass.php:**

```
<?php
        namespace Classes; 
       // ^ It doesn't work but when I replace "Classes" to "Test\Classes" It 
           works!
        // But why?
      Class Someclass
       {
         use Traits/Sometrait;
          //Yeah, It doesn't work too and when I replace "traits" to "Test\Traits" It  works!
         // Why? =(
          public static function start() {...}
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Answer (score 0):

You left out the most important part..
What is in

```
spl_autoload_register(...);
```

?

the function that you set here will determine how classes will be found in your project directory.

Take a look at this 
http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#3-namespace-and-class-names